# Excel.exe not found when running python

Tags: python

My code below opens all Excel files in a directory.

It runs well in Jupiternotebook and I copy it into a ".py" file.

Then I run that .py file on cmd windows and I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: The process "excel.exe" not found.
OPEN EXCEL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\new.py", line 28, in <module>
    display(ExcelApp)
NameError: name 'display' is not defined
```

I did successfully install "pip install pypiwin32" in cmd.

Can you please help to fix?
Many thanks. HHC

```
from win32com import client
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

#create an instance of Excel & make it visible
ExcelApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
ExcelApp.Visible = True
display(ExcelApp)


#Get name of all files to be opened
import os; import glob
path = f'C:\\Users\\Excel file to open\\'
files = os.listdir(path)
print(files)

excel.Visible = True

#Open files
for i in files:
    print(i)
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open( path + str(i))
```

Comment: Where is the display function defined? Is it a method, that is object.display(ExcelApp)

Comment: I see what is the problem. Thank you. HHC